# Android sqlite INNER JOIN que devuelva un array

Tags: java, android, array, sqlite

Estoy usando sqlite para android y quiero una función que me devuelva un array con todos los objetos que cumplan una condición. Me explico:

Tengo dos tablas:
Películas

```
private static final String CREATE_PELICULAS_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + PELICULAS_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_PELICULA_ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_PELICULA_PORTADA + " BLOB NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_PELICULA_DIRECTOR + "TEXT NOT NULL"
                + ")";
```

Pendientes

```
private static final String CREATE_PENDIENTES_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + PENDIENTES_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_PENDIENTES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli + " LONG NOT NULL );";
```

En la tabla pendientes se encuentran los ID de las películas que han sido agregadas como pendientes. Quiero una función que mediante un inner join me devuelva un array con todas las películas cuyo ID se encuentra en pendientes.

Lo que es la query imagino que vendría a ser algo como esto:

```
private final String QUERY= "SELECT * FROM PELICULAS_TABLE a INNER JOIN PENDIENTES_TABLE b WHERE a.KEY_PELICULA_ID=b.KEY_PEN_IDSerieOPeli";
```

Imagino que tendría que usar también rawQuery, pero no lo tengo claro.

Pero no acabo de entender como hacer una función que me devuelva mediante un array todas las películas encontradas.